# How to print special characters with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing web page in slovak language. To be able to use meantioned language special characters such as á or ž, I am using this html code:

```
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
```

Now it works as expected but only when I hard code that kind of text into html file.

As soon as I use jquery to print them it breaks down and those characters are not correctly shown.

```
$("#myDiv").html("áž");
```

Am I supposed to specify something in jquery or is there another way to overcome this problem?

Comment: It works well http://jsfiddle.net/bhu2u/, if you put the code in a js file, check the encoding of that file.

Comment: It should work fine. I guess it could be because the source code (.html, .php or whatever that is) file is not in the correct encoding.

Comment: Try saving your file in UTF-8 encoding. No reason for this to not work.

Comment: Special characters should be used like &#926;

Comment: @C-link What if these special chars are variable?  Should OP user define every such character?

Comment: “Not correctly shown” is not a problem description. What actually happens? This would help in guessing the nature of the encoding problem.

Comment: What happens is that instead of those characters it prints rubbish such as (�).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the numeric entity for that character into the html() function to achieve that,

Try a sample,

```
$('body').html('&#926;');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3qkYa/)

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be use some tricks here

Try this

```
$("#myDiv").html($("<div>").html("áž").text());
```

Or simply try this

```
$("#myDiv").text("áž");
```

Comment: May be you can try the .text()?

Answer (score 2):

It is quite Easy you can do the following
Use any special Character u want

```
$("#mydiv").text("*&^&*^*&^*");
```

Here is the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/naKX5/2/)

Comment: I know it works fine in fiddle but there has to be some error on my side with encoding, I just can't find out where.

Comment: check your id's of the element or u can use whole element in jquery reference , if it is there , jquery is case-sensitive u know , recheck your elements reference(id'class). and try it , if u have found your answer don't waste your time, try to accelerate yourself with another method which is providing you the correct answer

Comment: I know, problem is not that the characters would not be printed at all so there is no problem with wrong selector. It's just that it prints rubbish instead of those characters.

Comment: did u find your answer with another method ??, if not then gimme your fiddle link here , i'll try to help you .if and only if ,u did not find the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49522/discussion-between-thedean-and-matus-dubrava)